# how i can get the return value from java set<String> in another class in java

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, hashmap

How i can get the return value in other class using java set method.
I have include my program any body please tel me how i can get the return value from the other class.

```
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    public static Set<String> crunchifyPermutation(String str) {
        Set<String> crunchifyResult = new HashSet<String>();
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (str.length() == 0) {
            crunchifyResult.add("");
            return crunchifyResult;
        }

        char firstChar = str.charAt(0);
        String rem = str.substring(1);
        Set<String> words = crunchifyPermutation(rem);
        for (String newString : words) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= newString.length(); i++) {
                crunchifyResult.add(crunchifyCharAdd(newString, firstChar, i));
            }
        }
        return crunchifyResult;
    }

    public static String crunchifyCharAdd(String str, char c, int j) {
        String first = str.substring(0, j);
        String last = str.substring(j);
        return first + c + last;
    }

}
```

How i can get the return value for another class i was tried in

```
crunchifyPermutation c = new crunchifyPermutation();
Set<String> z = cr.crunchifyPermutation(ring);
```

but it return in `[ ]` only how I can get the all value in String.

Comment: what is ring and what does it contain? also: set<String> won't compile, please provide the correct code

Answer (score 1):

if you want a comma-separated list of the values then

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

// ...
Set<String> z = cr.crunchifyPermutation(ring);
String zAsString = z.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: Does lambda expression exists in Android SDK?

Comment: umm nope. the question didn't mention that it is android (although it is tagged) sorry